# Free windows firewall with date/time rules

Tags: windows-7, firewall

Can someone suggest such a firewall? I've tried set-up windows 7 firewall with scheduled scripts, but that didn't seem to work. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Most routers have date/time rules. But if you're looking for software firewalls, try Comodo. It's pretty well rated and has pretty substantial rule capability. I've run it for a few years since ditching ZoneAlarm when it became too bloated.

Comment: Thanks! Just checked and there is no date/time based rules, any other suggestions?